# Xamarin.Forms 2.4 is loosing hidden entry background on iOS

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

Recently I have switched to Xamarin.Forms 2.4.0.18342 and now on iOS (10 and 11) the default white background for Entry controls is lost if the control was hidden and then shown.

A simple layout:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical" Padding="50">
    <Button Text="Hide" Clicked="OnHideClicked"/>
    <Button Text="Show" Clicked="OnShowClicked"/>
    <Entry x:Name="PasswordEntry" Placeholder="Password" HeightRequest="44" AutomationId="PasswordStyleId" IsVisible="true"/>
</StackLayout>
```

looks like this:

[image: before hide]

But if I tap the **Hide** and then **Show** buttons with the following code behind:

```
void OnHideClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PasswordEntry.IsVisible = false;
}

void OnShowClicked(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    PasswordEntry.IsVisible = true;
}
```

the white background is no longer there:

[image: after hide and show]

**Update 1**

It works fine on Xamarin.Forms 2.3.4.270, but breaks on 2.4.0.280.

**Update 2**

Xamarin Bug: [60261](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=60261)

Comment: Have you tried to set default background color white such like BackgroundColor="White" of the entry?

Comment: That is one of the workarounds possible, but I would like to avoid this. Especially that I don't want white background on other platforms.

Comment: But anyway, I will end up having combined this white background + OnPlatform :(